# How to stop Google indexing of hidden elements?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

`Theme by Colorlib Powered by WordPress.` shows up in Google search results, below my site title, despite having used css to hide it.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="site-info col-sm-6">
            <div class="copyright-text">
                                </div>
            <div class="footer-credits">
                Theme by <a href="https://colorlib.com/" target="_blank" title="Colorlib">Colorlib</a> Powered by <a href="http://wordpress.org/" target="_blank" title="WordPress.org">WordPress</a>               </div>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tried:

```
.footer-credits {display: 
none;)
```

Doesn't work.

Tried:

```
.footer-credits 
{visibility: hidden;}
```

Doesn't work.

So how can I use css to hide it?

Would my hosting provider know and be able to modify server?

Comment: You could create a child theme from the current theme and override the name with something of your kind. This wouldn't fix the problem of that showing up, but it will show up with the words you want.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about SEO which is off topic here. Please delete this and, instead, ask on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ (btw, using CSS to hide content will not solve the issue and might be considered "black hat" which will get you in trouble with Google search.)

Comment: For using css to hide my footer credits? Im sure not. What would solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent most search engine web crawlers from indexing a page on your site, place the following meta tag into the

```
<head>
```

section of your page:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

To prevent only Google web crawlers from indexing a page:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

You should be aware that some search engine web crawlers might interpret the noindex directive differently. As a result, it is possible that your page might still appear in results from other search engines.

I *think* it is not possible with CSS but not *sure*.

Check detail on this [link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en) (copied from this source)

Comment: Thank but i want Google to index the page, just not the words contained above.